# Benefits of using Crucible with FishEye for mercurial, any other decent alternatives?

Tags: code-review, mercurial

I have an experience of using both github and stash for corporate repos and both tools a very mature and indeed are very handy for pull request based code reviews.

Unfortunately, there's no option to use this soft with mercurial. I had tried rhodecode, and rhodecode is something almost on the brink of being unusable. Here are the main reasons why:

- Pull requests are immutable. That means that you can not introduce new changesets to the existing PR, and adding changesets is something essential to code review approach actually.
- Pull requests do not merge automatically after the approval. In fact, neither it is possible to do manually, via web interface.
- In [some cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24993637/rhodecode-how-to-add-to-pull-request-only-changes-that-had-been-introduced-afte) Rhodecode mistakenly adds changesets to PR that are not supposed to be there.
- The user limitation implementation is weird - if you have N-users license, N plus first user can be added, it's just that now everybody including the users that had been already registered, will get the "You have reached the maximum number of users (N), please contact support to extend your license. "

So I keep searching for the enterprise (installed in intranet, not in an external cloud) web interface for mercurial code reviewing. It looks like Atlassian Crucible is just something I need, but I'm lost a little bit on what's the role of FishEye in this case.

As far as I can understand, FishEye provides just viewing capabilities (so it is like hg serve on steroids) while Crucible introduces peer reviews. Do I understand correctly?
Can I use Crucible without FishEye and if I can, is it still recommended to use is along with FishEye?

May be there are other decent alternatives I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FishEye appears to be basically hg serve on steroids.

Crucible is basically a private-cloud Bitbucket

Crucible has some minimal integration with FishEye, so you can click on files and changesets to view them in FishEye, and a couple of other insignificant bits of integration. Definitely, they can be used independently.

[Source](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CRUCIBLE/What+happens+if+I+decide+to+stop+using+FishEye+with+Crucible)

Answer (score 0):

You might consider checking out [Deveo](http://deveo.com). It supports Mercurial branch based code review workflows in addition to Bookmarks based code reviews. You can see the workflow in action from the below blog post (there's also a youtube video): http://blog.deveo.com/mercurial-code-reviews/ Deveo is paid software, but it offers a 45-day free trial. It can be hosted on your own hardware or used from our multi-tenant cloud.

(Disclaimer: I work at Deveo)